# iOS 11 beta, if I try request image from photos library, I see wrong size image all time

Tags: ios, objective-c, photos, beta, ios11

I try to get small images in my size, but I always see 120x120 images. They are less then I need.

It happens only in iOS 11 beta

My example:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
requestOptions.synchronous = YES;
requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
requestOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(320.f, 320.f) contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *resultImage, NSDictionary *info) {

}];
```

Comment: File a radar, this seems like unintended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the resize mode from PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast to PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact.

```
requestOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
```